# Split Anonymous Function into Terms

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I am wanting to take a matlab anonymous function of something like `@(x) = x + x^2` and split it into a cell array so that

```
f{1} = @(x) x
f{2} = @(x) x^2
```

I want to be able to do this with some arbitrary function handle. The best that I have come up with so far is taking in `@(x) = x + x^2` as a string and splitting it by the addition signs and appending `@(x)` to the beginning of this. However, I would like to be able to directly use a function handle as the function argument. It would also be nice as using other variables could lead to some difficulty in the string approach.

I am also considering just taking in a cell array of function handles as an argument, which would be more difficult for the user but easier in my code.

For some background, I'm wanting to do this for some least squares data fitting code that I am writing for a class. This code will be for taking in a model function as an argument and I need to evaluate each term separately for the least squares process. I'm not limiting these models to polynomials and even if a polynomial is the model, I want the option to leave out certain powers in the polynomial. If someone has a better suggestion for taking a model function, that would be great too.

**UPDATE:** Someone wanted to know what I meant by

> I'm not limiting these models to polynomials and even if a polynomial
>   is the model, I want the option to leave out certain powers in the
>   polynomial.

For some clarification, I was saying that I didn't want to limit the models to

```
c0 + c1*x + ... + cn*x^n
```

in which case I could just take in `n` as a parameter and create terms from that similar to what happens in `polyfit`. For example, if I know that my input data fits an even or odd function, I may want one of the following models

```
c0 + c1*x^2 + c2*x^4 + ... + ck*x^(2k)
c1*x + c2*x^3 + ... + cm*x^(2m-1)
```

Where `k` is even and `m` is odd. Or possibly a model that isn't strictly a polynomial, but keeps the coefficients linear, such as

```
c0 + exp(x) * ( c1 + c2*x + ... cn*x^(n-1) )
```

Comment: I think you are on the right path. You can use the `str2fun` and `fun2str` functions to convert between a string and a function handle, which should solve your problem, right? Are you parsing with `regexp`? Because then you should be able to do it independently of variable names (and probably even number of variables?)

Comment: Could you please extend, what you mean with *I'm not limiting these models to polynomials and even if a polynomial is the model, I want the option to leave out certain powers in the polynomial.*?  A second example would be nice!

Comment: Instead of trying to decompose a single function handle into multiple functions that are part of it, e.g. by splitting at the addition sign, you could provide multiple function handles (the parts) that then would be added together in any possible combination to find what combination of functions yields the best least-squares result. A downside is that you can make many combinations if you provide many function handles as the input.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of using string manipulation on functions, but maybe that is just me. One alternative could be to use symbolic expressions as input.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you want, but is converting a function handle to a data structure similar to [such a tree](http://www.polberger.se/components/read/figures/8.png) what you want?

Comment: @Daniel It looks like the solution given by Luis works for my needs, but that does sound interesting. Do you have any information about doing that in matlab?

Comment: Why not simply use `Fs = {@(x) x.^2, @(x) x, @(x) 1}`? It's a lot more obvious and general. Also there are no problems with capturing variables. I don't think it makes it really difficult for the user. Doing conversions to strings back and forth is really odd and might introduce hidden bugs when we missed some special case of the `func2str` conversion. (Imagine somebody using extra parentheses for example: `@(x) (x + (x+1)*sqrt(x) + x^2 + exp(x+2));` Why should the result depend on the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. The string should not be split at `+` signs that are within a parenthesis group. For example, with

```
f = @(x) x + (x+1)*sqrt(x) + x^2 + exp(x+2);
```

the string should be split at the first, but not at the second `+` sign.

This can be accomplished as follows. To detect only `+` signs that are outside parentheses, add 1 for each opening parenthesis and subtract 1 for each closing parenthesis. Then the desired `+` signs are those with count 0.

I'm assuming the output should be a cell array of function handles. If it should be a cell array of strings just remove the last line.

```
F = functions(f);
str = F.function; %// get string from function handle
[pref, body] = regexp(str, '@\(.+?\)', 'match', 'split'); %// pref is the '@(...)' part
body = body{2}; %// body is the main part
ind = cumsum((body=='(')-(body==')'))==0 & body=='+'; %// indices for splitting
body(ind) = '?'; %// '?' will be used as split marker
ff = strcat(pref, strsplit(body, '?')); %// split, and then add prefix
ff = cellfun(@str2func, ff, 'uniformoutput', 0); %// convert strings to functions
```

Result in this example:

```
ff{1} =
    @(x)x
ff{2} =
    @(x)(x+1)*sqrt(x)
ff{3} =
    @(x)x^2
ff{4} =
    @(x)exp(x+2)
```

Comment: I never thought about a `+` that didn't separate terms, so thanks for mentioning that! It looks like this will solve the problem that I'm having  and the regex fixes my issues with different variables.

Comment: Glad about it :-) Yes, I thought of several variables too. The regexp only looks for the first pair of parentheses, no matter what's inside